# A question about column editing in Emeditor

Tags: csv, text, edit, emeditor

I have 5 columns:

[image]

How can I get this result?

[image]

Thank you..

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Do you want to take the rightmost cell from each row to create a column?

Comment: Hello yes that's right, sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you open the CSV file, click the **Extract Columns** button on the **CSV/Sort** toolbar. In the **Extract Columns** dialog box:

1. Reverse the order of columns 2 - 5. To do this, you can drag and drop items in the list, or use the **Up**/**Down** buttons.

[image: EmEditor - Extract Columns dialog box]

2. Select the columns 2 - 4, and set the **Combine with previous column** and **Use first non-empty value** options.
3. Click **OK**.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I have been busy recently and thank you very muchhh!!